# Solving $\int_0^2 x^a (2-x)^b dx$ by using beta function

Tags: integration, substitution, beta-function

I'm wondering which substitution I need to transform the integral:

$$
\int_0^2 x^a (2-x)^b dx
$$

so that the endpoints will become $0$ and $1$ , and the second argument of the form $(1-x)^c$ in order to solve it by using the beta function.

Comment: You should use $x=2y$. You'll find $c=b$.

Comment: Hello @J.G. thank you very much for your precious suggestion. Can you take a look to this question please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4381786/solving-int-02-zn-a-2-2-z-1b-dz-by-using-beta-function

Comment: I've looked. Unfortunately, until @peek-a-boo's latest comment is addressed, there's nothing more to say.