# Solving $\int_0^2 z^{n-a-2} (2-z^{-1})^b dz$ by using beta function

Tags: integration, substitution, beta-function

I'm wondering which substitution I need to transform the integral below like the integral in the definition of the beta function (I know that $a>-1$ and $b>-1$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$):

$$
\int_0^2 z^{n-a-2} (2-z^{-1})^b dz
$$

I tried the substitution $y=z/2$, but I got an integral where there is the term $\frac{1}{2y}$ which is difficult to manage:

$$
\int_0^2 z^{n-a-2} (2-z^{-1})^b dz =
2 \int_0^1 (2y)^{n-a-2} \left(2-\frac{1}{2y}\right)^b dy =
2^{n-a-1} \int_0^1 y^{n-a-2} \left(2-\frac{1}{2y}\right)^b dy
$$

Comment: are you sure this integral is right? If $n=1$ and $a=b=0$, then this gives $\int_0^2\frac{dz}{z}=\infty$. The $z^{-1}$ term really messes things up.

Comment: Hello @peek-a-boo thank you for your comment. My goal is to find to values of $a$ and $b$ such that the above integral is finite. In order to do this I prefer to express it as a beta function, in this way it's easier to impose the constraints on the exponents (e.g. if I have the function $y^{n-a-1} (1-y)^b$, then the constraints are $n-a>0$ and $b>-1$, but this is not the case of my example).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the beta function. Also, the term $(2-z^{-1})$ is negative for small values of $z$, so you can't raise it to arbitrary powers $b$. Perhaps you meant $\int_0^2z^{n-a-2}(2-z)^b\,dz$ (this is related to the beta function)? Or maybe $\int_0^2z^{n-a-2}|2-z^{-1}|^b\,dz$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo ok I made an error thinking that. Could you suggest me a way to understand for which values of a and b the integral is finite please? If necessary I can change the title of the question. Should I do it?

Comment: The issue is not even with finiteness. It'd about well-definedness of the integrand. You can't exponentiate a negative number to an arbitrary real number $b$ (unless you want to start getting into complex analysis, branch cuts and blablabla) So, until you answer my previous comment about what integral you actually mean, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is a special case of the incomplete beta function:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{2} z^{n-a-2}\left(2-\frac{1}{z}\right)^b dz = \int_{0}^{2} z^{n-a-2-b}(2z-1)^b dz$$

Making the substitution $ w = 2z$

$$ I = \frac{(-1)^b}{2^{n-a-1-b}} \int_{0}^{4} w^{n-a-2-b}(1-w)^b dw$$

The incomplete beta function is defined by

$$ B(v;\mu; x) = \int_{0}^{x} t^{v-1}(1-t)^{\mu-1}dt \quad 0\leq x<1\quad \mu \in \mathbb{R}, v >0 $$

However, if $\mu$ is a positive integer, an extension to arguments exceeding unity is possible:

$$B(v;m;x+1) = \frac{(m-1)!}{(v)_{m}} -(-1)^{m}B\left(m;1-v-m;\frac{x}{x+1}\right) \quad x\geq 0 \quad m=1,2,3,...$$

where

$(v)_{m} = v(v+1)(v+2)\cdots(v+m-1)$ is the rising factorial or Pochhammer polynomial.

Applying this extension to your integral and supposing $b+1\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$:

$$ I = \frac{(-1)^b}{2^{n-a-1-b}} \left[ \frac{b!}{(n-a-b-1)_{b+1}} -(-1)^{b+1}B\left(b+1; 1-n+a; \frac{3}{4} \right)\right] $$

Therefore, if $ b+1\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $n-a-1-b>0$:

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{2} z^{n-a-2}\left(2-\frac{1}{z}\right)^b dz = \frac{(-1)^b}{2^{n-a-1-b}} \left[ \frac{b!}{(n-a-b-1)_{b+1}} -(-1)^{b+1}B\left(b+1; 1-n+a; \frac{3}{4} \right)\right]}$$

Comment: Hello @Bertrand87 thank you very much for your answer.